# AutoFill chrome extension not updating the ng-model values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

I build a small auto fill chrome extension using jquery. when i click this extension the values are updated in view of my angular app. but the modal values not updated. how to update the modal values

In my content.js i have a code like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.each($('body').find('input:visible'),function(data,element){
           var arr=[];
           for (var i = 0, attrs = element.attributes, n = attrs.length, arr = []; i < n; i++){
               $.each(valueFillers,function(d,e){
                 if(valueFillers[d].stringmatch.indexOf(attrs[i].nodeValue.toLowerCase())!=-1){
                         console.log(valueFillers[d].stringmatch)
                         $(element).val(values[d]);
                         setTimeout(function () {
                            $(element).triggerHandler('input');
                         });
                   }
               });
            }
        });
    })
```

how to bind this values to ng-model. pls Help

Answer (score 1):

Please see the jQuery documentation for .trigger and .triggerHandler

http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

It says triggerHandler will execute the handlers added using jquery while .trigger will execute all hanlders. Please try using .trigger method instead .triggerHandler